# Would you replace these deck posts? How much life do they have left?

Tags: deck, post

I have a small deck that needs care. The top side is in really bad shape (rails, floors, lattice, stairs) need to be replaced. The deck is above a brick patio and I think that the posts are set in concrete buried under the patio bed.

I am trying to decide if I need to replace the posts as well. I am not very charmed by the idea of having to dig out the posts, the concrete and to pour concrete footing (quicrete and quicktube like [here](https://www.quikrete.com/athome/video-deck-footings.asp://)-not sure if quckrete is OK for this)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit them with a hammer to hear if they are solid. If the are rotting they will sound flat or hollow, if they are solid you can hear it.

You could also power wash them to get a better look at their condition.

From here they look fine. But then looks can be deceiving.

Good luck!

Comment: I agree they look good but the hammer test will tell for sure. +

Comment: Thaks a lot guys, I did not think about that ...I will give it a try.